# Where is the public rpm signing key for artifactory install rpms

Tags: artifactory

I am intending to try artifactory using the rpms to install it, the rpms in the repo are signed but to validate them will require the key

```
$ rpm --checksig jfrog-artifactory-cpp-ce-6.5.3.rpm
jfrog-artifactory-cpp-ce-6.5.3.rpm: (SHA1) DSA sha1 md5 (GPG) NOT OK (MISSING KEYS: GPG#d7639232)
```

Where can we download the public key GPG#d7639232 ?

Alec Keeler

Answer (score 1):

The key that signs the `repomd` metadata is [here](https://bintray.com/jfrog/artifactory-pro-rpms/download_file?file_path=repodata%2Frepomd.xml.key).   You can retrieve the public key that signs the rpms themselves by invoking this [Bintray API](https://api.bintray.com/orgs/jfrog/keys/gpg/public.key) - It retrieves the key matching the organization that published these rpms (in our case [JFrog](https://bintray.com/jfrog/artifactory-pro-rpms/jfrog-artifactory-pro-rpm#files/org%2Fartifactory%2Fpro%2Frpm%2Fjfrog-artifactory-pro%2F6.5.3))

Comment: This question is related to the keys used to sign the Artifactory installation rpms, not keys generated by or used by Artifactory itself.

Comment: @alecKeeler see my revised answer